# A problem relating to Schwarz' lemma

Tags: complex-analysis

**Question.** Let $f:D\rightarrow D$ holomorphic s.t. $f(1/2)+f(-1/2)=0$. Show that $|f(0)|\leq1/4$

**My attempt at a solution:** This seems like a Schwartz-lemmma type question (as discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464604/bounds-of-fz-for-specific-z-via-schwarz-lemma-and-the-such)). If we could find a holomorphic function $\varphi:D \rightarrow D$ s.t.
$$\varphi(0)=1/2 \\ \varphi(1/4) = 0$$
Then we could define
$$g(z)=\frac{1}{2}\left[f(\varphi(z))+f(-\varphi(z))\right].$$
Since $g:D\rightarrow D$ is also holomorphic, and $g(0)=0$ we would have (by Swartz lemma)
$$|g(z)|\leq |z|,$$
and in particular,
$$|f(0)|=|g(1/4)|\leq 1/4.$$

I tried to find a Möbius map $\varphi$ that would satisfy the required conditions, but I'm pretty such $\varphi$ does not exist.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $f$ has a power series expansion $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ that converges in $D$. Now, if $g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{2n}z^n$ then
$$
\forall z\in D,\quad g(z^2)=\frac{1}{2}\left(f(z)+f(-z)\right)\in D.
$$
Since every $z$ in $D$ is the square of an element from $D$ we conclude that $g(D)\subset D$. Moreover, $g(1/4)=0$ by assumption.

Now if $$\varphi(z)=\dfrac{4z+1}{4+z},$$ then $\varphi(D)=D$ and $\varphi(0)=\frac{1}{4}$, hence $g\circ \varphi(D)\subset D$ and $g\circ \varphi(0)=0$, so, by Schwarz lemma we conclude that $|g\circ \varphi(z)|\leq |z|$ for every $z\in D$.

In particular, for $z=-\frac{1}{4}$ we obtain $|g(0)|\leq \frac{1}{4}$. But this is the same as $|f(0)|\leq \frac{1}{4}$.$\qquad\square$